# Activity does not start when called from a method

Tags: android-activity, localization, oncreate

I have an activity class (A) and a non activity one (B). In A are some methods useful to B, in particular from B I call a method of A that shuold return the coordinates (actually A performs localization through GPS provider). The problem is that when I call A from B, the activity does not start and I obtain an exception.

How can I start an activity from a method, called by another non activity class???

I tried different solutions, but neither of them worked. I tried for example to start the onCreate() tiping this instruction in the method:

Bundle tempBundle = new Bundle();

onCreate(tempBundle);

This is the method of the activity class:

```
   public double GetCoordinates(boolean value) { 

    Bundle tempBundle = new Bundle();
    onCreate(tempBundle);

    if(value) 
        coordinate = latitude; 
    else 
        coordinate=longitude;

    return coordinate; 
   }
```

And these are the instructions in the non activity class:

```
            Localization loc = new Localization();

            LATITUDE = loc.GetCoordinates(true); 

            LONGITUDE = loc.GetCoordinates(false);
```

Any hints please??